# How can I remove scrollbars from an iframe using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a page that I don't control the source to.  It contains an iframe.
The iframe has scrollbars and a border.  I want to remove both.
I tried using Jquery like this:

```
$('iframe').attr('scrolling', 'no');
```

Nothing I do will affect the iframes attributes at all.

Any ideas? (IE8)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/frames.html#h-16.5

```
<iframe scrolling="no" frameborder="0">
```

Comment: I can't change the html, I can only inject script.

Answer (score 1):

You can **access the iframe's attributes using jQuery**, and simply **set the scrolling to "no"** like this:

```
$("#frame")[0].setAttribute("scrolling", "no");
```

Just be sure to append the [0] as above, so the jQuery object will return the first DOM element.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 0):

`frameborder="0"` I believe for the border part. You could play around with css overflow for the scrolling, not exactly sure about that.

Comment: Same as the other answer, I don't have control of the html.  Hence the reason I am trying to affect it with some injected jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$("iframe").each(
     function(index, elem) {
         elem.setAttribute("scrolling","no");
     }
 );
```

I didn't test it but it should work.